# How to display an Image sent through HTTP (Node.js) in the Front End using Fetch?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I'm trying to Fetch a URL (http://localhost) that will return a picture (At this moment, the extension doesn't matter) through HTTP using Node.js.

**Front End**

```js
let image = await fetch('http://localhost:3031', {
   mode: 'cors',
   method: 'GET'
})
```

**Back End**

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    fs.readFile('image.png', (err, data) => {
        res.write(data, "binary");
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(3031)
```

I want to take that picture and then display it into the Website.

Im getting the file, NOT THE SRC

Comment: you mean setting the src of an image-tag? Can you post your html codes?

Comment: Is not the src I need, because I'm passing the complete file through HTTP

Comment: There is probably no point in `fetch`ing an image at all on the Client. Just use `<img src='yourSource.png' />` in HTML or `imgElement.src = 'yourSource.png';` in Front End JavaScript.

Comment: The thing is im using TWAIN and WAI in the command line to get the picture from an Scanner. So you mean i have to upload that picture to another server soIi can get a src

Comment: If you're serving the image at `http://localhost:3031`, that's what you set its `src` to, i.e. `<img src="http://localhost:3031" />`. Usually, you only need to fetch the image in your script if you want to somehow process its binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly in the HTML as:

```
<img id="loadedimage" src="http://localhost:3031/"/>
```

Or with `fetch`, using `createObjectURL`:

```
var element = document.getElementById('loadedimage');
var response = await fetch('http://localhost:3031');
var image = await response.blob();
element.src = URL.createObjectURL(image);
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/bortao/pen/oNXpvYR

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much!